# Webpack + AngularJS 1.6 ui.router 1.x not loading ui-router properly

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-router, webpack-2

I'm using the new UI router.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.6"
}
```

using webpack to build the project. my app.js to bootstrap the app looks like,

```
import angular from 'angular';
//import uirouter from 'ui.router';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

angular
.module('app', [
  uiRouter
]);
```

For dependencies I have tried injecting uiRouter and uirouter and (ui.router & ui-router & angular-ui-router).

Nothing seems to be working. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the right injection name `ui.router`. Also ensure that you using ui-router version `0.4.2` while `1.0.x` has some problems with AngularJS 1.6.

```
import angular from "angular"
import "angular-ui-router"

angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
```

#### Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "0.4.2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to import ui-router 1.x like this:

    `import uirouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';`

and before this, if you are using TypeScript, try to specific your ui-router's path in **tsconfig.json** as

```
"paths": {
        "@uirouter/angularjs":["node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/lib/index.d.ts"]
}
```

Should be fine then.